# Ag-Grid Add custom column to agColumnsToolPanel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a requirement to add an extra column to column side menu in Ag grid
is that possible in Ag-Grid

[image]

UPDATE my question

I figure half of the solution to create a custom tool panel and start drawing the columns but I face three issues with that

1- scroll not working
2- columns panel overlap with status bar
3- drag and drop not working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yjpquk?file=App.tsx,customStatsToolPanel2.tsx

current solution result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I checked the link you provided and was able to resolve the overlap and scrolling issues.

```
const divStyle={
overflowY: 'scroll',
border:'1px solid red',
width:'500px',
float: 'left',
height:'500px',
position:'relative'
};
```

This style can be used in a container div, and it will function properly.